# Dropdown list in KnockoutJS not binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to make the values from the database appear in the dropdownlist .
I sucessfully displayed the data using the table but when i added the dropdownlist (`<select>`) it stops there. I can't figure out the problem.

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr>
    <th>Choice Text</th>
    <th>Zero Tolerance Message</th>
    <th>Has SubChoice</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: choice">
    <tr>
     <td>
         <label data-bind="text: ChoiceText,visible:IsUsed"></label>
         <input type="text" data-bind="value: ChoiceText, visible: !IsUsed()" >
     </td>
     <td>
         <label data-bind="text: ZeroToleranceMessage, visible: IsUsed"></label>
         <input type="text" data-bind="value: ZeroToleranceMessage, visible: !IsUsed()" />
     </td>
     <td>
         <label data-bind="text: HasSubChoice, visible: IsUsed"></label>
         <input type="text" data-bind="value: ZeroToleranceMessage, visible: !IsUsed()" />
         <select data-bind="options: controlType, optionsText: 'ControlType', optionsCaption: 'CT', optionsValue: 'ControlTypeId'"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Below that are these scripts:

```html
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/knockout.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {

            $('th > :checkbox').click(function () {
                $(this).closest('table')
                    .find('td > :checkbox')
                    .attr('checked', $(this).is(' :checked'));
            });
        });

        var viewModelChoiceJSON = ko.mapping.fromJS( $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Model.choiceJsonData)'));
        var viewModelControlTypeJSON = ko.mapping.fromJS( $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Model.controlTypeJsonData)'));
        //Html.Raw(jsonData)
        ko.applyBindings({ choice: viewModelChoiceJSON });
        ko.applyBindings({ controlType: viewModelControlTypeJSON });
    });

</script>
```

Controller:

```cs
public ActionResult ChoiceList(int? questionId)
{
    _ValidationService = DiFactory.Resolve<IValidationService>();
    _ChoiceService = DiFactory.Resolve<IChoiceService>();
    ChoiceViewModel viewModel = new ChoiceViewModel(_ChoiceService.GetChoice(questionId));
    viewModel.choiceJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( _ChoiceService.GetChoice(questionId));
    viewModel.controlTypeJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_ValidationService.GetControlType());
    //  viewModel.ControlTypeSource = Utility.ControlTypeSource();
    return PartialView("~/Areas/Validation/Views/Choice/ChoiceGrid.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Model.controlTypeJsonData)')` and the one before it?  And where is the code for your dropdown?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: here is the code for the dropdown `<select data-bind="options: controlType, optionsText: 'ControlType', optionsCaption: 'CT', optionsValue: 'ControlTypeId'"/>`

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand @Html.Raw(Model.controlTypeJsonData) returns<br/>`[{"ControlTypeId":1,"ControlType":"Textbox             "},{"ControlTypeId":2,"ControlType":"CheckBox            "},{"ControlTypeId":3,"ControlType":"RadioButton (Yes/No)         "},{"ControlTypeId":4,"ControlType":"DropDownList        "}]`    when i display $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Model.controlTypeJsonData)') in a message box (alert) it returns [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @allengopico Note that you can (and it's preferred if you do) edit your own question to add details, fix formatting and spelling, etc. There's an "Edit" button below your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't apply bindings twice for the same context. Change your JavaScript to:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    choice: viewModelChoiceJSON,
    controlType: viewModelControlTypeJSON
});
```

And in HTML, where you binding options specify $root before controlType:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.controlType, optionsText: 'ControlType', optionsCaption: 'CT', optionsValue: 'ControlTypeId'"/>
```